# Understanding intermediary SQL statements in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

So I have table, and I want to have users be able to view the table in whichever order they'd like. Here's an example:

```
class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    amount = Column(Integer)
    date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now())

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount
```

So I'd like to make the following query:

```
 if sort == 'amount':
     orderby = Thing.amount.desc()
 elif sort == 'date':
     orderby = Thing.date.desc()

 things = DBSession.query(Thing).order_by(orderby).all()
```

Main questions:

1. When I set the orderby statement, am I actually calling anything or is the statement just being set?
2. Am I doing this correctly and efficiently?
3. Can I do this similarly with filters?

   filterby = Thing.amount == 5

   things = DBSession.query(Thing).filter_by(filterby).all()

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ans 1:**
When you are giving any syntax what exactly it will return you can check with type of that syntax like

When you write

```
In [5]: Thing.amount.desc()
Out[5]: <sqlalchemy.sql.expression._UnaryExpression object at 0x199a5d0>
```

It will create one object of type expression._UnaryExpression. So this expression you can give to sqlalchemy when we want unary operation. Now when you print it 
    In [6]: a = Thing.amount.desc()

```
In [7]: print a
thing.amount DESC
```

So when query run it will be converted in `thing.amount DESC`. So when you create expression it will not call any thing, it will just create structure of query.

**Ans: 2**
When you are creating query it will create object which is needed. For filter and order by it need expression so if you pass directly to the `order_by` or `filter` then it will create object for the same internally. So you can use both way.

**Ans: 3**

```
In [8]: Thing.amount == 5
Out[8]: <sqlalchemy.sql.expression._BinaryExpression object at 0x1a1dbd0>
```

This is also a expression so you can give expression to [filter_by](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by).

You will get more idea about [expression](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html) from sqlalchemy site.